# Trying to access Lua scripts in assets via require on Android

Tags: android, ant, lua, android-ndk, sdl-2

I've recently tried porting an engine I've been working on to Android and have ran into some problems when trying to use "require" or "dofile" within a lua script.

(quick note: this is written in C++11, using ndk-build and ant to compile on windows 7)

Compiling Lua (Version 5.3) was pretty simple and I used the following article to get access to the internal assets directory:
[50ply blog post on loading compressed android assets](http://www.50ply.com/blog/2013/01/19/loading-compressed-android-assets-with-file-pointer/)

I added an output in the replaced fopen function to help debug this issue and when I run:

```
luaL_dofile(LuaS, "scripts/test.lua");
```

I get:

```
>> scripts/test.lua , read
```

Which is perfect for me and runs the file in the assets/scripts folder, but when I try to run the following line in the lua script:

```
local derp = require("scripts.noop")
```

I get:

```
>> /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/scripts/noop.so , read
```

After looking through the Lua source code, this path seems to be the "LUA_CDIR" as defined in "luaconf.h", which also explains why it looks for *.so files instead of *.lua... So I'm not sure why it's looking for the LUA_CPATH instead of the LUA_PATH or how to fix this.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great and if I could do this by overwriting the search path/settings outside of the Lua source, it would be even better.

Sorry if this question is not well written, if any further information is required, I will provide it. I'm in a bit of a rush right now.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time of things if you copy the files from assets to the actual filesystem.  Assets is not a directory on the device, so anything looking for a file won't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require checks both `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` with many different combinations found within `package.path` and `package.cpath`. Environment variables `LUA_PATH` and LUA_CPATH can be found merged into package actually, as preparation goes.

Psuedo-c/c++-example:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "path");
lua_getfield(L, -2, "cpath");
const char* cpath = lua_tostring(L, -1);
const char* path = lua_tostring(L, -2);
lua_pop(L, 3); // field 2, field 1, package table
printf("cpath: `%s`\n", cpath);
printf("path: `%s`\n", path);
```

Which is almost equivalent to, minus the print calls:

```
>print(package.cpath)
.\?.dll;C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\?.dll;C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\loadall.dll
>print(package.path)
.\?.lua;C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\lua\?.lua;C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\lua\?\init.lua;
```

Here is an example of require working:

```
>require("abc")
 (Runtime) | Stack Top: 0 | [string "require("abc")"]:1: module 'abc' not found:

        no field package.preload['abc']
        no file '.\abc.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\lua\abc.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\lua\abc\init.lua'
        no file '.\abc.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\abc.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\LuaConsole\bin\loadall.dll'
 --
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string "require("abc")"]:1: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x00401c80
```

The solution of your problem is to have your assets directory fall into a directory found within `package.cpath` or `package.path`. As @GabeSechan suggested in the comments, "You'll probably have an easier time of things if you copy the files from assets to the actual filesystem. Assets is not a directory on the device, so anything looking for a file won't find it." So if you are able to get this situated, go for it!

Comment: Your advice lead to debugging the paths and it turns out using the Lua line
    package.path = "?.lua"
gives access to the assets directory. So I'm taking your post is the answer to my terribly written question.